# Alter views fields using preprocess function before render?

Tags: views, theming

How do I edit a views field using preprocess before it is rendered to the screen?
Let's say the field originally outputs something like this:

```
Note title
```

now I want to change that adding the number of comments in that node

```
Node title (4 comments, 1 new)
```

I know I can achieve this with joining two fields together or altering the template (tpl) files for that particular field but I'd like to learn how to use **preprocess** function in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 7**

Either you have to use [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) or create appropriate TPL file (e.g. views-view-fields--MYVIEW.tpl.php) in your template dir (check Theme:Information in view edit page for more details).

You may also use preprocess theme function to print a single record from a row, with fields which is [template_preprocess_views_view_fields()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7).

Related:

- [_preprocess_views_view__ specify view name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22878/preprocess-views-view-specify-view-name)
- [Drupal 7 preprocess_views not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433853/drupal-7-preprocess-views-not-working)
- [Specific preprocess functions for theme hook suggestions are not invoked](https://www.drupal.org/node/939462)

Answer (score -1):

There is help on [Using default views in your module](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-default-views).

I also found this how-to helpful: [Theming a view from within your module](http://www.appnovation.com/theming-view-within-your-module).

Comment: First link doesn't work. 2nd one is for Drupal 6 only.