# _preprocess_views_view__ specify view name

Tags: views, theming

I have a view named "taxonomy_term_custom." The preprocess code below works to do some specific stuff for this view, but I would like to override the hook like this:

```
function mywebsite_glue_preprocess_views_view__taxonomy_term_custom(&$vars) {
}
```

Is this possible?

```
function mywebsite_glue_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if($vars['view']->name == 'taxonomy_term_custom'){
    dpm($vars);
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 7 this preprocess function will not automatically get picked up as it did in Drupal 6. There is a workaround posted [here](http://drupal.org/node/939462#comment-4476264) if you want the same behaviour as Drupal 6. For the [issue.](http://drupal.org/node/939462)

Comment: Is it just `hook_preprocess_views_view()` that is affected? I've looked through the issue and can't find a definitive list of which hooks are affected.

Answer (score 5):

Just call preprocess for each view.

```
function mywebsite_glue_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $function_name = __FUNCTION__ . '__' . $vars['view']->name;
  if (function_exists($function_name)) {
    $function_name($vars);
  }
}

function mywebsite_glue_preprocess_views_view__taxonomy_term_custom(&$vars) {
  dpm($vars);
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that depends on which version of Drupal you are using though. Watch out for [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/258089). It says that you can't have a views preprocess function unless you have a corresponding tpl file.